# Lava V2 s stuck on company logo after deleting Launcher 3 and System UI

Tags: unbricking

I have rooted Lava V2 s running on Android 5.1 and mistakenly deleted some system apps: Launcher 3, and System UI. The phone is starting up but cannot go into the home screen. Instead, it directly goes to power off and has stuck on the company logo while booting up.

How to fix the boot issue?

Answer (score -1):

In this state, you just need to flash your phone. 
Go [here](http://firmwarefile.com/lava-v2s) and download the firmware for your phone model